# Cannot understand why this code doesn't work. I have some trouble with my sql database. $sqll="SELECT * FROM netbarg WHERE r_number='02177736'"

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code. I know this number(02177736) is stored in database. I'm completely new in php and mysql.

```
  $sqll="SELECT *  FROM netbarg WHERE r_number='02177736'";
        $result=mysql_query($sqll,$connection);
$ro= mysql_fetch_array ($result);
var_dump($ro);
```

but it returns false to me. I have no idea. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is r_number an alfanumeric field?

Comment: a) **don't use mysql** - it's been deprecated and in PHP7, removed. use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. b) have you tried the query in phpMyAdmin or similar? c) have you looked at mysql_error?

Comment: What datatype is 02177736 column? TEXT, VARCHAR, INT?

Comment: im tried in phymyadmin.

Comment: data type of 02177736 is varchar(20)

Answer (score 0):

You should check for errors and report them, e.g.

```
$sqll="SELECT *  FROM netbarg WHERE r_number='02177736'";
$result=mysql_query($sqll,$connection);
//check for errors!
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$ro= mysql_fetch_array ($result);
var_dump($ro);
```

Also, you should using something *other* than the mysql_ functions as are deprecated - see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: then the row does not exist

Comment: the row exist.but my field has white space.i use some methods and remove white space and spaces.so my broblem solved.

Answer (score 0):

User mysqli_query insted of mysql_query and the first pass connection and then your query.

```
$sqll="SELECT *  FROM netbarg WHERE r_number='02177736'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sqll);
//check for errors!
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$ro= mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
var_dump($ro);
```